# Which weapons can V display on their Apartment Stash Wall?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

In V's apartment, there's a weapons locker, The Stash, with a bunch of convenient weapon-sized cutouts in the walls. It turns out, that when you place *certain specific weapons* in your stash, those weapons will be displayed in those cutouts, turning the wall into a nice little trophy room.

So far, every weapon that I've managed to make display is an Iconic weapon  - mostly, but not all, linked to storyline quests (three were crafted). Currently, I have managed to fill niche's with:

- **Buzzsaw**, a crafted iconic SMG
- **Sovereign**, a crafted iconic Shotgun
- **Comrade's Hammer**, a crafted iconic Revolver
- **Overwatch**, an iconic Sniper Rifle from a quest
- **La Chingada Dorada**, a iconic Pistol found at Coyote Cojo some time after completing *Heroes*
- **Plan B**, an iconic Pistol found in the junkyards outside Night City
- **Satori** an iconic Katana found on the rooftop during *The Heist* main story mission.

But there's still 11 weapons missing that I haven't found. What's the complete list of weapons that V can mount on their trophy wall, and where can they be found?

[image: The wall in V's stash, with a few weapons in it.]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is 19 weapons that will show up on the display wall and where to get them

1. Breakthough - tech sniper rifle - open world skull, loot recipe off boss, must craft epic first, then legendary, location:
   [image]
2. Overwatch - power sniper rifle - Panam's quest reward
3. Moron Labe - power assault rifle - open world skull, loot recipe off boss, must craft epic first, then legendary, location:
   [image]
4. Psalm:11:6 - power assault rifle - open world skull, loot recipe off boss, it will be blue, you will have to craft blue, epic then legendary, location:
   [image]
5. Buzzsaw - power submachine gun - open world skull, loot recipe off boss, must craft epic first, than the legendary version, location:
   [image]
6. Yinglong - smart submachine gun - open world skull, loot recipe off of boss, you can craft it as an legendary, no need to craft epic then legendary, location:
   [image]
7. Mox - power shotgun - Judy's quest reward, you can get this gun after the last mission for her, Pyramid Song, but it's different between male and female V.

   - if you are playing as a male V (judy can't be romance), all you need to do is go to her apartment after she gives you a copy her key and pick it up
   - if you are playing as a female V(didn't romance her), just go to her apartment and pick it up, after you get a copy of her key
   - but if you did romance her, after you get a copy of her key, just keep playing as normal, side/gig, or main missions until she text you, once you get a message from her, reply back, skip 24 hours and wait a bit for the next one and so on, until you get the message about her leaving something for you near the kitchen counter, note: you have to do side/gig or main missions until she text you, if you try to skip time to get her to start messaging you, it wont work, but after the first one, which is called OUR BD, then you can start skipping time to get the one for the gun
8. The Headsman - power shotgun - open world skull, when you get there, follow the road inside until you reach the end, then open the warehouse door, kill the robot inside and loot the recipe off of it, must craft the epic one before crafting the legendary version, location:
   [image]
9. Sovereign - power double-barrel shotgun - Open world, go to the location shown on the map which is a skull, loot the crafting recipe off the boss guy, must craft the epic one before crafting the legendary version, location:
   [image]
10. La Chingona Dorada - power pistol - after the quest *Heroes*, go outside, skip a day and go back into the bar, go where you place an item for jack, now you will find both of his hand guns.
11. Malorian Arms 3516 - power pistol - Johnny's gun - you will get it doing the mission *Chippin' In*
12. Plan B - power pistol - Dexter's gun, you will get it at the place where Takemura killed Dexter, South South-East of the Medeski Fuel Station. location:
    [image]
13. Skippy - smart pistol - get it from a side mission, it wont show up in your journal, you will have to go there and get it, to put it on the wall, pick puppy loving pacifist once you pick it up, get 50 kills within 3 days, after that, wait for a while and he start talking to you again, pick no i'm keeping you, then you will be able to place it on the display, location:

[image]

(why puppy loving pacifist first?, after the 50 kills, the gun with auto switch to the next mode, leaving the first mode you pick locked, being stone cold killer is all headshots only, it's best to go with puppy loving first, so that mode will get locked and can't be picked again, then the weapon will get stuck on stone cold killer mode)

14. Archangel - power revolver - Kerry will give you this weapon after the side mission A Like Supreme, to get it to pop up, here is the order of missions that needs to be completed, main mission Search and Destroy, once you complete that, a side mission will pop up, Tapeworm, followed by Chippin' In, a cool metal fire (which get's completed the same time as chippn' in), Blister Love, Holdin On, Second Conflict, then A Like Supreme, kerry will hand you the gun at the end of the mission
15. Comrade's Hammer - tech revolver - open world skull, loot the recipe off the boss guy, must craft the epic one before crafting the legendary version, location:

[image]

16. Crash - power revolver - complete river's missions
17. Jinchu-maru - katana - loot from Oda during the parade mission (main mission), once you take out the 3 snipers, the next part is going for a netrunner, once you get to the netrunner, Oda will show up - defeat him and loot the sword
18. Satori - katana - pick it up doing the heist mission at the start of the game, instead of going outside on the ledge with jack, go upstairs then take the stairs to the roof, you will find it in the shuttle thing, then go back down stairs and onto the ledge to finish the mission
19. BA XING CHONG - Smart Shotgun - There is a few steps to take to get this one, first you must kill adam smasher doing the main mission, loot his body and finish the game, 2nd you must have edgerunner artisane in tech, which allows you to craft legendary weapons, if you have done both, follow this video here (not my video, credit goes to xGarbett):

There is a secret spot on the display wall that you can't see, until you place the gun on the wall, here are 2 pics:

Without the gun on the wall:

[image]

With gun on the wall:

[image]

Comment: Are all these weapons labelled as iconic in the game?